# Import package plugin to Django project

Tags: python, django, import, plugins, modulenotfounderror

I have Python project in which i have plugins with setup.py and Django project in the same level.
I want to use those plugins I made inside of Django app views but it cannot find modules I am trying to pass.[image]

- graph_explorer is Django project.
- app_platform is Python package plugin which is not django app.
- api is another Python package plugin which is not django app.

[image]

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

from app_platform.app_platform import main

# Create your views here.
def home(request):

    return HttpResponse(main())
```

1. In home/views.py I am just trying to call method of app_platform dummy method and I am getting ModuleNotFoundError app_platform.
2. Then i put this code inside of settings.py of Django project

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# Add the parent directory of app_platform and api to the Python path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'app_platform')))
```

[image]
3. I get pass first ModuleNotFoundError for app_platform but now I get ModuleNotFoundError for api package which was imported inside of app_platform
[image]

```
import pkg_resources

from api.data_source_api import DataSourceBase
from api.visualizer_api import (
    VisualizerBase
)


def app_platform_test() -> str:
    return "test_method"


def main():
    plugins = []
    for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group="visualizers"):
        p = ep.load()
        print(f"{ep.name} {p}")
        plugin = p()
        plugins.append(plugin)
        if issubclass(p, VisualizerBase):
            plugin = p()
            if hasattr(plugin, 'render'):
                plugin.render(None)
                plugins.append(plugin)
            else:
                print(f"Plugin {ep.name} nema metodu render().")

    xml_data = """
                    <trains>
                        <train id="1">
                            <name>Express</name>
                            <route>New York to Chicago</route>
                        </train>
                        <train id="2">
                            <name>Local</name>
                            <route>Chicago to San Francisco</route>
                        </train>
                    </trains>
                    """

    for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group="data_sources"):
        p = ep.load()
        print(f"{ep.name} {p}")
        plugin = p(xml_data)
        plugins.append(plugin)
        if issubclass(p, DataSourceBase):
            plugin = p(xml_data)
            if hasattr(plugin, 'fetch_data'):
                plugin.fetch_data()
                plugins.append(plugin)
            else:
                print(f"Plugin {ep.name} nema metodu render().")
    return plugins

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/67579). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).